# Creating ethane using \chemfig

Tags: macros, chemfig

I was tinkering with chemfig package. 
I created the macros

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\lmethyl}{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)}
\newcommand{\rmethyl}{C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H}
\newcommand{\tmethyl}{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)-H}
\newcommand{\bmethyl}{C(-[4]H)(-[6]H)-H}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{\lmethyl-\rmethyl}
\end{document}
```

I thought I would be able to create the code of methane using this. I know the macros are all run at the same time and hence creates the following.
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `\definesubmol{name}{code}` command.
You can insert a sub-molecule inside a chemfig command with `!{name}`.

```
\definesubmol{rmethyl}{C(-[0]H)(-[2]H)(-[6]H)}
\chemfig{R-!{rmethyl}}
```

There are some other things you can do with that command, such as defining different code depending on what direction the bond comes from (so H_3C and CH_3 can be handled by one sumbol).

For more details, see section 4.7 of the [chemfig manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig).

Answer (score 10):

You should use `chemfig`'s `\definesubmol` instead of `\newcommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol{\lmethyl}{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)(-[6]H)}
\definesubmol{\rmethyl}{C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H}
\definesubmol{\tmethyl}{C(-[2]H)(-[4]H)-H}
\definesubmol{\bmethyl}{C(-[4]H)(-[6]H)-H}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{!\lmethyl-!\rmethyl}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thats what I wanted!
Just one more question, what does the ``!`` do in ``\chemfig{!\lmethyl-!\rmethyl}``

Comment: The `!` is the operator that tells `chemfig` to insert a submol. You may also define a submol without backslash: `\definesubmol{Et}{CH_3-CH_2}`. Then you need to use it like `\chemfig{!{Et}-H}`